# Simplify boolean xy + xy’z + x’yz

Tags: boolean, boolean-expression, simplify

I'm trying to prove that XYZ + XYZ' + XY'Z + X'YZ = XY+ XZ + YZ

I have gotten so far i think. I don't know if I am on the right track but i keep getting stuck when i end up with this xy + xy’z + x’yz....

here is what i have done:

F(X,Y,Z) = XYZ + XYZ'+XY'Z + X'YZ

XYZ + XYZ’ + ZXY’ + XYX’  (Commutative)

XY(Z) + XY(Z’) + ZXY’ + ZYX’ (associative)

XY(Z+Z’) + ZXY’ + ZYX’ (distributive)

XY(1) + ZXY’ + ZYX’ (inverse)

XY + ZXY’ + ZYX’ (identity)

and as you can see... i get stuck here... cause i need to have XY + ZX + ZY but i can't get rid of the two last negatives..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics (Boolean algebra), not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

> XYZ + XYZ' + XY'Z + X'YZ 
>   = (XYZ + XYZ + XYZ) + XYZ' + XY'Z + X'YZ 
>   = (XYZ + XYZ') + (XYZ + XY'Z) + (XYZ + X'YZ) 
>   = XY(Z + Z') + X(Y + Y')Z + (X + X')YZ 
>   = XY + XZ + YZ

Comment: Nice and sweet. Informally it is also quite obvious: "Either all three are correct, or two are correct and one false" is the same as "At least two of these three must be true".

Comment: how did you get that first line??? the rest makes perfect sense and thanks so much, but I'm at a loss with how i can add two more xyz? i just want to know for future so i can learn where i was going wrong.

Comment: @tiinkx: For any *foo*, *foo* = *foo* + *foo*. Or, if you prefer, *foo* = *foo* · 1 = *foo* · (1 + 1) = *foo* · 1 + *foo* · 1 = *foo* + *foo*.

Comment: so is that like a law?? @ruakh

Comment: @tiinkx: I'm not sure "law" is the right word, but -- yes. + is defined such that 0 + 0 = 0 and 1 + 1 = 1. Since 0 and 1 are the only two possible values, we have that *foo* + *foo* = *foo* for both possible values.

Comment: As ruakh said, it is formally defined to be so; but informally you can see for yourself it works. "A + B" in logic means "A or B". If you have "A", then you also have "A + A + A" because... see here: if you know "sun is orange", then you also know that "sun is orange, or sun is orange, or sun is orange". Makes sense?